# Build a JSON object and send it from Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, http-post

I want to build the following `JsonObject` from Excel VBA and send it to a web server using `POST` query :

```
{
    "processDefinitionId":"7892112646445148463",
    "variables":[{"name":"environment","value":"DEVOO"},
                 {"name":"srvName","value":"SRVTEST"},
                 {"name":"srvType","value":"Cloud"}]
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON)

Comment: @Tom I dont have the right to install libraries on my computer

Comment: There is no need to build any object. You just sent a string with the provided text via XHR method POST.

Comment: Tom's sample does not require installation of libraries. There is plauin text source code that you take into your project and use the routines provided by that code

Comment: Anybody have a link to a solution that does not require GitHub access? Asking from behind a firewall...